# How to bulid mono-fastcgi-server on yocto for intel x86 board

Tags: mono, monodevelop, mod-mono, xsp, fastcgi-mono-server

i am trying to build mono web applications with nginx for linux platform with yocto worrier branch

i have made changes on below conf file
1)

```
conf/local.conf

PACKAGE_CLASSES ?= "package_deb"
EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES ?= "tools-sdk"

CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL += "mono mono-xsp libtool ca-certificates mono-dev sqlite autoconf automake make libevent-dev libgdiplus libxft libevent packagegroup-core-buildessential libxml2 libgdiplus "
```

2) conf/bblayers.conf

```
BBLAYERS ?= " \
  /home/administrator/yocto-warrior/poky/meta \
  /home/administrator/yocto-warrior/poky/meta-poky \
  /home/administrator/yocto-warrior/poky/meta-yocto-bsp \
  /home/administrator/yocto-warrior/meta-openembedded \
  /home/administrator/yocto-warrior/meta-oe \
  /home/administrator/yocto-warrior/meta-mono \
  /home/administrator/yocto-warrior/meta-intel \
  /home/administrator/yocto-warrior/openembedded-core \
```

ERROR
ERROR: mono-xsp-git-r0 do_configure: oe_runconf failed

Comment: Can you switch to .NET Core? It is not a good option to go Mono today.

Comment: That error message alone is insufficient to understand what's wrong. Do you have logs? Or a verbose mode?

Comment: **Error**: You must have `libtool' installed to compile mono_fpm.
Get ftp://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/libtool-1.2d.tar.gz
(or a newer version if it is available)
Error: Exiting
Configure failed. The contents of all config.log files follows to aid debugging
ERROR: oe_runconf failed
WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
ERROR: Function failed: do_configure (log file is located at /home/administrator/yocto-warrior/build/tmp/work/core2-64-poky-linux/mono-xsp/git-r0/temp/log.do_configure.13200)

Comment: i have added `libtool` into meta-mono/reciepes-mono/mono-xsp/mono-xsp.inc file and also conf/local.conf